# Module not found: Can't resolve './AppAPI' in project folder

Tags: reactjs, npm, jscript

I have done everything right when setting up my react app and for some reason I'm getting this error.

All my code is in a .js file called App.API.js which is located in the src folder.

The error is coming from the index.js which has the code: import App from './AppAPI';

I've gone through several guides and other posts with similar questions but no solution is working. I have created a whole new react app and tried again but have had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

**change  :**

```
import App from './AppAPI'
```

**to :**

```
import App from "./App.API";
```

Comment: Yeah I shouldn't have asked this question, I saw the error right after I posted it. Thanks for  taking the time to reply though.